# Symfony + RabbitMQ + Ratchet

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, ratchet

I've set up websockets by this manual:
http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world
And it's work.

But now I need to send messages to clients from php, and I don't know how to do this.
I've found some manuals with rabbitMQ which I use in my project? like this:
https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/659
but I can't understand how to use it.

Maybe someone knows?

Answer (score 0):

You can create [Symfony console command](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html) to start RabbitMQ consumer, start WebSocket server and send messages to a client once ones received from queue.

```php
 protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $loop = LoopFactory::create();
        $pusher = new MessageHandler();

        $queueAsyncClient = new AsyncClient($loop, [
            "host" => $_ENV['RABBITMQ_HOST'],
            "port" => $_ENV['RABBITMQ_PORT'],
            "vhost" => $_ENV['RABBITMQ_VHOST'],
            "user" => $_ENV['RABBITMQ_USERNAME'],
            "password" => $_ENV['RABBITMQ_PASSWORD'],
        ]);

        $connect = $queueAsyncClient->connect();

        // When client has connected, retrieve channel (as promise)
        $connect->then(function (AsyncClient $client) {
            return $client->channel();
            // Then declare the queue and exchange
        })->then(function (Channel $channel) {
            // These method calls all return promises, so we need to combine them
            return \React\Promise\all([
                $channel,

                // Create the queue we'll be using
                $channel->queueDeclare($_ENV['RABBITMQ_QUEUE'], false, true),

                // Declare an exchange
                $channel->exchangeDeclare($_ENV['RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE'], 'direct', false, true),

                // Bind the queue to the exchange
                $channel->queueBind($_ENV['RABBITMQ_QUEUE'], $_ENV['RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE']),
            ]);

            // Then, when the exchange is all hooked up, hook up the pusher
        })->then(function ($connection) use ($pusher) {
            /** @var Channel $channel (see first section of all() promise above) */
            $channel = $connection[0];

            // On messages, consume them using the pusher
            return $channel->consume(
                function (Message $message) use ($pusher, $channel) {
                    $content = json_decode($message->content, true);
                    $connections = $pusher->getUserConnections($content["uid"]);
                    foreach ($connections as $connection) {
                        $connection->send(json_encode($content["event"]));
                    }
                },
                $_ENV['RABBITMQ_QUEUE'],
                '',
                false,
                true // Acknowledges messages
            );
        })->done();

        $webSocketServer = new \React\Socket\TcpServer("tcp://0.0.0.0:" . $_ENV['WEBSOCKET_PORT'] . "/ws", $loop);


        $wsServer = new WsServer($pusher);
        $wsServer->enableKeepAlive($loop, 30);


        $ioServer = new IoServer(
            new HttpServer($wsServer),
            $webSocketServer
        );

        $loop->run();
    }
```

MessageHandler class (like `Pusher` from the Github issue) basically it stores all connections and handles connection open/close and message events.

```php
class MessageHandler implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    protected $connections;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connections = new SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->connections->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        try {
            $content = json_decode($msg, true);
            if ($content || !isset($content["uid"])) {
                $this->connections->rewind();
                while ($this->connections->valid()) {
                    if ($this->connections->current() === $from) {
                        $this->connections->setInfo($content["uid"]);
                    }
                    $this->connections->next();
                }
            } else {
                echo "Invalid message content: " . $msg;
            }
        } catch (\Throwable $t) {
           echo $t->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->connections->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, Exception $e)
    {
        $this->connections->detach($conn);
        $conn->close();
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $uid
     * @return ConnectionInterface[]|null
     */
    public function getUserConnections($uid)
    {
        $connections = [];
        $this->connections->rewind();
        while ($this->connections->valid()) {
            if ($this->connections->getInfo() == $uid) {
                $connections[] = $this->connections->current();
            }
            $this->connections->next();
        }
        return $connections;
    }

    /**
     * @return ConnectionInterface[]|null
     */
    public function allConnections()
    {
        $connections = [];
        $this->connections->rewind();
        while ($this->connections->valid()) {
            $connections[] = $this->connections->current();
            $this->connections->next();
        }
        return $connections;
    }
}
```